# Why do acronyms aviation often have words in orders unusual?

Tags: aviation-history, terminology

- "Airplane Single Engine Land" (rather than "Single Engine Land Airplane"
- "Certified Flight Instructor Instrument" (rather than "Certified Instrument Flight Instructor)
- "Medical Certificate Third Class" (rather than "Third Class Medical Certificate"; although AFAICT "Medical Certificate Third Class" is generally not used except as the title of the document itself)

It seems like aviation has a lot of acronyms with the words in orders unusual. Why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a cataloging practice (raised to an art form by the military) to place the root (or common) noun, (or root noun cluster) first, with variable adjectives following, in order to facilitate indexing. For example, all the medical categories can be listed under M in an index, and all the airplane categories can be indexed under A.  Way easier to find things.

Comment: Thank you! So it's basically for the same reason that book indexes often use phrases like "Gettysburg, Battle of"?

Comment: Exactly.  You could probably call it a universal publishing practice.

Comment: They make more sense if you insert commas after each word.  Or, say them in a Yoda voice.

Comment: Comedian, you are. Go for laughs, you do.

Comment: @TypeIA I made an edit to accommodate your comment.